# javascript setTimeout and google closure compiler

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have several setTimeout statements and after I run my code through the closure compiler, they don't seem to work.
I have 3 kinds of these statements:

1) Call a function:

```
setTimeout("MyFunctionName()", 3000);
```

2) jQuery

```
setTimeout("$('#MyDiv').find('.MyClass').addClass('TheNewClass');", 1000);
```

3) Global varible setting

```
setTimeout("MyGlobalVar = 2;", 2000);
```

What's the best way to optimize this kind of code?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closure compiler renames your functions and variables, thats why your code breaks. As a solution use an anonymous function like the following, so those calls get renamed, too.

1)

```
setTimeout( function() { MyFunctionName(); }, 3000);
```

or (as mentioned by jfriend00) as long as your function has no arguments:

```
setTimeout( MyFunctionName, 3000);
```

2)

```
setTimeout( function() { $('#MyDiv').find('.MyClass').addClass('TheNewClass'); }, 1000);
```

3)

```
setTimeout( function(){ MyGlobalVar = 2; }, 2000);
```

As for (2) I'm not sure, whether that's the only reason your code breaks.

Comment: The first item can just be: `setTimeout( MyFunctionName, 3000);`.  An anonymous function is not needed in that case.

Comment: Just left it in place to cover the more general case, when there are parameteres present.

Comment: on case 2, sometimes I have a boolean as parameter. Do I leave it as it?

Comment: @frenchie if you use the anonymous function you're on the save side anyways.

Answer (score 3):

The real problem is that you're passing code to `setTimeout` as a string, which you should **never** do because it is functionally equivalent to using `eval`.

[There are many reasons to not use `eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don%27t_use_eval!), including the fact that Closure Compiler can't "see" the code hidden away in strings.